# Need to add onblur to update ISA calculator results without clicking calculate

Tags: javascript, calculator, currency, finance, figure

```
    var initialAmount = parseFloat($('#initialAmount').val());
    var regularAmount = parseFloat($('#regularAmount').val());
    var regularFrequency = $("input[name='regularFrequency']:checked").val();
    var startDate = new Date($('#startDate').val());

    var ageAtStartDate = startDate.getFullYear() - dobDate.getFullYear();

    if (startDate.getMonth() < dobDate.getMonth() || (startDate.getMonth() === dobDate.getMonth() && startDate.getDate() < dobDate.getDate())) {
        ageAtStartDate--;
    }

    var currentYear = startDate.getFullYear();
    var currentTaxYearStart = new Date(currentYear, 3, 6);
    var nextYear = currentYear + 1;
    var nextTaxYearStart = new Date(nextYear, 3, 6);

    if (startDate >= currentTaxYearStart && startDate < nextTaxYearStart) {
        var totalContributions = initialAmount;

        if (regularFrequency === 'weekly') {
            var weeksDiff = Math.floor((nextTaxYearStart - startDate) / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            totalContributions += (regularAmount * weeksDiff);
        } else if (regularFrequency === 'monthly') {
            var monthsDiff = (nextTaxYearStart.getMonth() - startDate.getMonth()) + (12 * (nextTaxYearStart.getFullYear() - startDate.getFullYear()));
            totalContributions += (regularAmount * monthsDiff);
        } else if (regularFrequency === 'biannually') {
            var monthsDiff = (nextTaxYearStart.getMonth() - startDate.getMonth()) + (12 * (nextTaxYearStart.getFullYear() - startDate.getFullYear()));
            totalContributions += (regularAmount * (monthsDiff / 6));
        } else if (regularFrequency === 'annually') {
            var yearsDiff = nextTaxYearStart.getFullYear() - startDate.getFullYear();
            totalContributions += (regularAmount * yearsDiff);
        }

        var remainingAllowance = 20000 - totalContributions;

        if (remainingAllowance < 0) {
            var requiredContributions = 0;

            if (regularFrequency === 'weekly') {
                requiredContributions = (20000 - initialAmount) / weeksDiff;
            } else if (regularFrequency === 'monthly') {
                requiredContributions = (20000 - initialAmount) / monthsDiff;
            } else if (regularFrequency === 'biannually') {
                requiredContributions = (20000 - initialAmount) / (monthsDiff / 6);
            } else if (regularFrequency === 'annually') {
                requiredContributions = (20000 - initialAmount) / yearsDiff;
            }

            $('#result').html('<p class="text-danger">You have exceeded the annual ISA allowance.</p>' +
                '<p>Your age at the start date is ' + ageAtStartDate + ' years old.</p>' +
                '<p>Total Contributions for This Tax Year: £' + totalContributions.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') + '</p>' +
                '<p>Remaining Allowance for This Tax Year: £' + remainingAllowance.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') + '</p>');

            var nextTaxYearContributions;

            if (regularFrequency === 'weekly') {
                nextTaxYearContributions = (regularAmount * 52);
            } else if (regularFrequency === 'monthly') {
                nextTaxYearContributions = (regularAmount * 12);
            } else if (regularFrequency === 'biannually') {
                nextTaxYearContributions = (regularAmount * 2);
            } else if (regularFrequency === 'annually') {
                nextTaxYearContributions = regularAmount;
            }

            if (nextTaxYearContributions < 20000) {
                var remainingNextTaxYearAllowance = 20000 - nextTaxYearContributions;
                $('#result').append('<p>Remaining Allowance for Next Tax Year: £' + remainingNextTaxYearAllowance.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') + '</p>');
            }
        } else if (remainingAllowance >= 0) {
            var nextTaxYearContributions;

            if (regularFrequency === 'weekly') {
                nextTaxYearContributions = (regularAmount * 52);
            } else if (regularFrequency === 'monthly') {
                nextTaxYearContributions = (regularAmount * 12);
            } else if (regularFrequency === 'biannually') {
                nextTaxYearContributions = (regularAmount * 2);
            } else if (regularFrequency === 'annually') {
                nextTaxYearContributions = regularAmount;
            }

            if (nextTaxYearContributions > 20000) {
                var maxContributionsForNextYear = 0;

                if (regularFrequency === 'weekly') {
                    maxContributionsForNextYear = Math.floor(20000 / 52);
                } else if (regularFrequency === 'monthly') {
                    maxContributionsForNextYear = Math.floor(20000 / 12);
                } else if (regularFrequency === 'biannually') {
                    maxContributionsForNextYear = Math.floor(20000 / 2);
                } else if (regularFrequency === 'annually') {
                    maxContributionsForNextYear = Math.floor(20000);
                }

                $('#result').html('<p class="text-danger">Contributions for the next tax year exceed the annual ISA allowance.</p>' +
                    '<p>Your age at the start date is ' + ageAtStartDate + ' years old.</p>' +
                    '<p>Total Contributions for This Tax Year: £' + totalContributions.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') + '</p>' +
                    '<p>Remaining Allowance for This Tax Year: £' + remainingAllowance.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') + '</p>' +
                    '<p>Total Contributions for Next Tax Year: £' + nextTaxYearContributions.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') + '</p>' +
                    '<p>To stay within the allowance for the next tax year, you can contribute a maximum of £' + maxContributionsForNextYear.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') + ' ' + regularFrequency + '.</p>');
            } else {
                $('#result').html('<p>Your age at the start date is ' + ageAtStartDate + ' years old.</p>' +
                    '<p>Total Contributions for This Tax Year: £' + totalContributions.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') + '</p>' +
                    '<p>Remaining Allowance for This Tax Year: £' + remainingAllowance.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') + '</p>' +
                    '<p>Total Contributions for Next Tax Year: £' + nextTaxYearContributions.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') + '</p>');

                if (nextTaxYearContributions < 20000) {
                    var remainingNextTaxYearAllowance = 20000 - nextTaxYearContributions;
                    $('#result').append('<p>Remaining Allowance for Next Tax Year: £' + remainingNextTaxYearAllowance.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') + '</p>');
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (startDate >= nextTaxYearStart) {
        var remainingAllowance = 20000;
        $('#result').html('<p>Allowance for Next Full Tax Year: £' + remainingAllowance.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') + '</p>');
    }

     // hide placeholder
$("#imagePlaceholder").hide();
$("#currentYearChart").show();
$("#result").show();

var initialAmountSlider = getElementById()

updatePieChart(remainingAllowance);

initialAmountSlider.addEventListener("blur", submit)
```

});

```
function updatePieChart(remainingAllowance) {
    var currentYearChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('currentYearChart'), {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ['Used Allowance', 'Remaining Allowance'],
            datasets: [{
                data: [20000 - remainingAllowance, remainingAllowance],
                backgroundColor: ['#36254d', '#0195a7'],
            }],
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Current Tax Year Allowance Usage',
            },
        },
    });
}
```

});

```
        <!-- Tab 2 Content (Allocation) -->
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="newTab">
            <div class="container mt-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Calculator Inputs (Left Side) -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <form id="isaCalculatorForm">
                            <div class="form-group custom-slider">
                                <label for="initialAmount">Initial Investment</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="initialAmount" placeholder="£0">
                                <input id="initialAmountSlider" type="text" data-slider-min="0"
                                    data-slider-max="20000" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0"
                                    data-slider-tooltip="hide" style="height: 2px" />
                                <div id="initialAmountAlert" class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group custom-slider">
                                <label for="regularAmount">Regular Investment</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="regularAmount" placeholder="£0">
                                <input id="regularAmountSlider" type="text" data-slider-min="0"
                                    data-slider-max="2000" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0"
                                    data-slider-tooltip="hide" />
                                <div id="regularAmountAlert" class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group" id="how-often-buttons">
                                <label>How often will you invest?</label><br>
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                                    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded mr-2">
                                        <input type="radio" name="regularFrequency" id="weeklyRadio" value="weekly"
                                            checked> Weekly
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded mr-2">
                                        <input type="radio" name="regularFrequency" id="monthlyRadio"
                                            value="monthly"> Monthly
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded mr-2">
                                        <input type="radio" name="regularFrequency" id="biannuallyRadio"
                                            value="biannually"> Bi-Annually
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded">
                                        <input type="radio" name="regularFrequency" id="annuallyRadio"
                                            value="annually"> Annually
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="startDate">Start Date</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="startDate">
                                <div id="startDateAlert" class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="dobHidden">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Results (Right Side) -->
                    <div class="col-md-6 center-content">
                        <div class="card" style="background-color: rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.075); border: 0;">
                            <div class="card-body center-content">
                                <!-- Pie Chart Canvas (Initially hidden) -->
                                <canvas id="currentYearChart" width="200" height="200"
                                    style="display: none;"></canvas>

                                <!-- Image Placeholder (Initially displayed) -->
                                <img src="../TP Website project/img/plus-placeholder2.png" id="imagePlaceholder"
                                    alt="Image Placeholder" style="display: block;">

                                <!-- Result Content (Initially hidden) -->
                                <div id="result" class="mt-4" style="display: none;">
                                    <!-- ... Your result content here ... -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the above is some of my code for a project im doing through a work academy. It calculates the info a client inputs and teh results display after the calculate button is pressed, i need to make the results and pie chart automatically update after when the client updates any of the input fields without them having to click calculate again. I think i need to add onblur but not not having any luck with this. Help is massively appreciated.

Tried adding onblur but not too sure im adding it in correctly.

Comment: it would be helpful to add your HTML or a working snippet, but for now, you have to invoke any function related to updating results/charts whenever any input is changed.

Comment: Hey Mhd Alaa Alhaj, I have included my HTML into the answer from another user on the post (couldn't figure out any other way to do so). If you could take a look at it that would be amazing! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of this problem is that you need to add blur events the first time `calculate` is being called. This is a way you can do it:

```js
function initialize(array) {
    for (let item of array) {
        if (!item.classList.contains("initialized")) {
            item.addEventListener("blur", calculate);
            item.addEventListener("input", calculate);
            item.classList.add("initialized");
        }
    }
}

function calculate() {
    let first = document.getElementById("first");
    let second = document.getElementById("second");
    let third = document.getElementById("third");
    let fourth = document.getElementById("fourth");
    initialize([first, second, third, fourth]);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = parseInt(first.value) + parseInt(second.value) + 2 * parseInt(third.value) + 3 * parseInt(fourth.value);
}
```

```html
First <input id="first" type="number" value="1"><br>
Second <input id="second" type="number" value="1"><br>
Third <input id="third" type="number" value="1"><br>
Fourth <input id="fourth" type="number" value="1"><br>
<input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="calculate()">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Explanation:

- we have a `calculate` function
- which initializes the events if they were not initialized so far
- and computes a value
- I added a `blur` event because you wanted it to be added and an `input` element so on change stuff will be recalculated

If you want the events to be added even before the call to `calculate`, then you can add the events like I did outside the function and you can simplify then `calculate` to only the computation.

EDIT

As @Mhd Alaa Alhaj pointed out in the comment section, we have a button inside a form that does the postback. In order to avoid doing so, the button either needs to be changed to `<input type="button" value="calculate">` or prevent the default behavior on form submit or button click, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Hey Lajos, thanks so much for answering, still a little confused i think with the differing classes etc as i didnt include my HTMl- Ive added my HTML into your answer as i coudltn see any other way to included it- any chance you could have a quick look over and maybe edit your origional answer to fit my classes etc? That would be so much help and massively appreciated! Thank you

Comment: @Owen you will need to edit your question and add your HTML there. When you are done, please write a comment here and I 'll take a look.

Comment: @Owen we are close to reaching a solution that's acceptable to you, but your HTML should be part of your question and I will use that as a basis to append/edit my answer. Thanks!

Comment: apologies, could not figure out how to edit my original question but have done now and added the HTML in. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Owen happy to help! It looks like you have a form which is submitted when you click on calculate and your server-side does the computation. If you want to run the calculation on blur or input, then you will need to figure out whether you want to do it on server-side or client-side. If the calculation is to be performed on the server-side, then you will need to modify your code to send an AJAX request to your server rather than postback and trigger that AJAX request on blur or input

Comment: @Owen if you can move the calculation code to the client-side, then an approach like mine will help you. So, the question is: is there any particular reason why you have placed the calculation on the server-side?

Comment: sorry correct me if im wrong but i believe the code already is client-side? The form data is processed on the client-side, and the chart rendering also happens in the client's browser using Chart.js?

Comment: @Owen I do not know, you did not provide a reproducible example and when I tested your code, it was postbacking. But, if it is indeed happening on the client-side, then you could implement a function like `function triggerCalculate() {document.querySelector(".btn-primary").click()}` and then set `onblur="triggerCalculate"` and `oninput="triggerCalculate"`

Comment: @LajosArpad you are mostly did the work and the PO is not doing the calculation in the server-side, the only issue is that the button is of `type="submit"` so the page will definitely make a postback. 
change the button to `type="button"` and it will stop making postback.
Another approach is to leave the button as is and make sure to `e.preventDefault()` on click.

Comment: @MhdAlaaAlhaj thanks for your comment, you are correct. I have edited my answer accordingly.